# Storing a password in an encrypted cookie?

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, active-directory, ldap

I know it is not best practice to store a password in a cookie, even if the data is encrypted.

However, I have a web application that needs to be able to search against Active Directory and, as far as I can tell, it requires that the user first binds using their credentials. This means that for each search request, I need to pass the user name and password to the DirectoryEntry constructor.

Given these constraints, is there an alternaive to storing the password in a (secure) cookie?

In absence of something better (e.g. getting a service account), the solution that I'm contemplating is either to store the credentials in an encrypted cookie or cache the DirectorySearcher object.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running the site with Windows Authentication and just trying to bind without the username and password?

Comment: @Rich, unfortunately that won't work because this service needs to be available non-domain computers (e.g. off-campus computers, student laptops, iPads, and smart phones).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could store the credentials server-side, generate a unique identifier for them, and store this identifier in a cookie. You can make the identifier expire if needed.

Comment: Fortunately I was able to get a service account which obviated the need for storing the password. I accepted your answer since it's similar to what I would have done.

Answer (score 1):

Store the password in a [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) Variable, this variable will expires if alive beyond the SessionTimeOut period.